# how do I enable digital delivery in the new paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I'm recreating my test environment.  I created new business and buyer accounts.  I setup the business account as best as I remember including the IPN info.

I attempt to make a purchase using ExpressCheckOut and I get back an error message:

> You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods.

We are selling a subscription so we are in fact performing a digital delivery.  Seems like I remember having to get a PayPal CS person to enable this feature on our live account.  Is there something special I need to do in the sandbox?

I opened a new PayPal account to replace my developer account.  It doesn't seem like a good idea to use the company live account.  Is this unexpected?

Comment: please try not to trick the system next time .. improve the question instead .. welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: Excuse me... "trick the system"?  in what way was I trying to trick the system?  I thought this was pretty straight forward question.

Answer (score 0):

The setting needs to be enabled via PayPal agents. Go ahead and send me an email via my profile details including your test account email address and I will enable this for you.

Comment: Glad I could get you taken care of. Feel free to contact me again if you reach another roadblock.